# Azure data gateway & logic apps - storing sql server login details

Tags: azure-logic-apps, data-gateway

With azure data gateway and powerbi, credentials used by the gateway to connect to each source are configured within the powerbi service.

When using the gateway with logic apps, i cannot find a similar way to set up credentials to data sources.
e.g. in the logic app, i am calling a sql stored procedure. I just specify the gateway and the username/password and it works.

I am unsure where i can alter the username and password should i wish to change them.

Appreciate any advice on managing data source credentials when using logic apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using most connectors in Logic Apps, especially ones that require credentials on some kind, an `API Connection` resource is created the same resource group as the Logic App.

You can update the credentials for any such API Connection by navigating to the *General > Edit API Connection* blade of the API Connection resource.